# Angular wait for Meteor call to return a value

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I am trying to show results of the Meteor.call on my template once the call has successfully returned data. When the template loads up it does not show any data, since the constructor in ClientsList reached its end, but meteor call inside of it is still running (asynchronous).

```
Client side code (clientsList.js):

import template from './clientsList.html';
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';

class ClientsList {
    constructor() {
        Meteor.call('getClients', function (error, response) {
            if (error) {
                // If our API returned an error, we'd see it in the console.
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log(response);
                this.clients = response;
            }
        });
        console.log('End of constructor');
    }   
}

const name = 'clientsList';

export default angular.module(name, [
    angularMeteor
]).component(name, {
    template,
    controllerAs: name,
    controller: ClientsList
})
}
```

Template (clientsList.html):

```
<ul>
        <li ng-repeat="client in clientsList.clients">
                {{client.Name}}

        </li>
    </ul>
```

How can I make my template wait for constructor in ClientsList to fully receive value "this.clients" before showing them.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: imho, a ctor is a terrible place to make an async call. the purpose of the ctor is to simply construct the object, not do everything needed to use it later.

Comment: You can't force it to wait. You need to deal with it by using a subscription and a helper method